# создать блок(меню ul>li) в js без использования html

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно сделать меню(ul>li*5) в js без html, изначально body в файле index.html должен быть пустой, все необходимые элементы генерируются с использованием JS
Как можно сделать проще, чтоб не создавать каждый li вручную?

```
const menu = document.createElement('ul');
menu.className = 'menu';
document.body.prepend(menu)
const menuItem= document.createElement('li');
menuItem.className = 'menu__item';
menuItem.innerHTML = 'пункт 1'
menu.append(menuItem)
```

Comment: Использовать цикл?

Comment: надо что то типа json или object  и его распарсить в в такой список - не сложно вроде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я предположу что вот так

для начала создадим object с именами и ссылками и потом его распарсим

тег h1 вставил просто так - что бы показать что вставили список до первого элемента на странице

информацию брал [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document)

```js
let list = [{
    name: "num1",
    link: "http://google.com"
  },
  {
    name: "num2",
    link: "http://yandex.com"
  },
  {
    name: "num3",
    link: "http://yahho.com"
  }
];

let ul = document.createElement("ul");
let ocum = "";

for (lis in list) {
  ocum += `<li title=" ${list[lis].link} ">
              <a href=" ${list[lis].link} " > ${list[lis].name}</a>
            </li>`;
}
ul.innerHTML = ocum;

document.querySelector("body").prepend(ul);
```

```html
<h1>hello word</h1>
```

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но вместо создания общего `ul`, под каждый `li` создаётся собственный)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 исправил вроде, спасибо за подсказку а то прошляпил бы

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю больше)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let col = 5,
    menu = document.createElement('ul');

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'menu__item';
  li.innerHTML = 'пункт '+(i+1);
  menu.append(li);
};

menu.className = 'menu';
document.body.prepend(menu);
```

---

По массиву

```js
let arr = [
      'пункт 1',
      'пункт 2',
      'пункт 3',
      'пункт 4',
      'пункт 5'
    ],
    menu = document.createElement('ul');

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'menu__item';
  li.innerHTML = arr[i];
  menu.append(li);
};

menu.className = 'menu';
document.body.prepend(menu);
```